# How is a time series with strong seasonality and trend stationary?

Tags: time-series, statistics

I was playing around with time series and stationarity and stumbled on something which I'm not getting completely.

There are two popular ways of testing out stationarity - ADF and KPSS. And I was using both(KPSS with a constant trend) on different time series and see how it works.

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, kpss
def _check_stationary_adfuller(x, confidence, **kwargs):
    result = adfuller(x, **kwargs)
    if result[1]>confidence:
        return False, result
    else:
        return True, result
    
def _check_stationary_kpss(x, confidence, **kwargs):
    result = kpss(x, **kwargs)
    if result[1]<confidence:
        return False, result
    else:
        return True, result
```

First I did the usual synthetic time series:

1. White Noise - Both tests gave non-stationary
2. White Noise with trend - ADF said Non-stationary, and KPSS said stationary (because we are running the version which allows for constant trend)

Till now things were as expected. Now I started with some real world time series.

1.
[image]

ADF: Non Stationary, KPSS: Stationary

Which I assumed was because of a slight trend in the time series. I tried removing the trend by fitting a linear trend and taking that out, but KPSS still seems to say that it was not stationary.

2.
To experiment further, I artificially enhanced the trend in the series by adding a manually created trend to it.
[image]

Now the most startling thing happened. Both ADF and KPSS started to tell that this is a stationary series. I tried running KPSS without the constant trend and thankfully it said the series was not stationary.

Now the questions are:

1. Why would adf be so wrong and say that this was stationary?
2. Is it good practice to always do multiple tests and make a voting decision to check for stationarity?
3. Would detrending with a linear fit normally make a trend stationary series into a stationary series?

Comment: both ADF and KPSS, remove the trend, so what remains is stationary or not

Comment: If my understanding is right, ADF looks at autoregression and KPSS is based on regression.. and for KPSS there is a way to do the rest so that a constant trend is also considered to be stationary. In statsmodels, there is a parameter, regression="ct" which makes the implementation invariant to a constant trend...

Comment: I think at least KPSS can handle even non-linear/constant trend. Check the documentation